# How to save data to database reads from EXCEL file using SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, oledb, sqldataadapter

i'm trying to save data to the database which retrieve from the Excel file. For that i'm using  SqlDataAdapter. But the data is not getting saved. Except excel data, other data is getting saved correctly. The issue is only with excel data. Here is my Code:

```
public static void Update(DataTable dt)
    {

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblsupplierorderitems (color, size) VALUES (@color , @size)", connection);
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@color", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40, "color");
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@size", SqlDbType.VarChar, 24, "size");

            adapter.Update(dt);
        }

    }
```

Any Suggestions to get this done? Also i need  to remove the empty rows from the DataTable dt.

Comment: Are you able to read your excel data in dataset properly??

Comment: Yes!. I have loaded the data into a datatable. And im passing that datatable into above method.

Comment: In what way does the data not save properly? Are you receiving any errors? Are you sure that the `DataTable` contains the requires columns and structure?

Comment: yeap..I set the row state dynamically to Added. then it worked. As I realized when we receiving data from excel file, the row state is Unchanged. So i set to Added to get it done.